# Cannot complete Bluetooth pairing process when pairing request appears in icon bar (versus a dialogue box with pairing request)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Summary of my problem**: some phones have a pairing requirement where the user has to click on "pair" from a dialogue box. However,  some of those manufacturers make that request a notification so it doesn't "block" the user I guess?

**A more in depth description of my problem**: Let me preface by saying that some phones don't have this problem ( I.e: Samsung s6, note 4, s7, Galaxy A9 were tried and don't require the "pair" dialogue box - those phones ran Android 6 and 7).

When my pairing process is done, I get the ACL_CONNECTED, then I get the dialogue box that will pop up on certain phones ( LG g6 running android 8.0). However, on other phones such as the Pixel 1 ( running Android 8.1), and Moto G, the pairing request appeared as a notification on the top. When that notification would appear, I would get an error on my Bluetooth device ( Error 10, but that error is only a reference for the device , which means "Pairing has not completed completely").

**My question**: would there be anyway to stop my application to wait for a user to click on the pair button? I.e: put sleep, a timer ( which I tried but it still seems to fail...) , maybe even by pass that requirement by some phone manufacturer? Or, get a handle on that dialogue to force it to open up? I'm not too sure what to do about this bluetooth issue.